# How can I import (with webpack) just the core of bluebird.js?

Tags: promise, bluebird

The [getting started](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) page says how you can directly download a core version of the bluebird library: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.core.min.js

However it doesn't say anywhere how to do the same with import (when using webpack) in order to avoid large build-size.

How do we do it?

Comment: It's a very important question. Seems like not many people are using bluebird these days

Comment: It's got 11 million weekly downloads, it says here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird